# C# Regex match on special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I know this stuff has been talked about a lot, but I'm having a problem trying to match the following...

Example input:  "test test 310-315"

I need a regex expression that recognizes a number followed by a dash, and returns 310.  How do I include the dash in the regex expression though.  So the final match result would be: "310".

Thanks a lot - kcross

EDIT: Also, how would I do the same thing but with the dash preceding, *but* also take into account that the number following the dash could be a negative number... didnt think of this one when I wrote the question immediately.  for example: "test test 310--315" returns -315 and "test 310-315" returns 315.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+(?=\-)");
```

`\d+` - Looks for one or more digits

`(?=\-)` - Makes sure it is followed by a dash

The `@` just eliminates the need to escape the backslashes to keep the compiler happy.

Also, you may want this instead:

```
\d+(?=\-\d+)
```

This will check for a one or more numbers, followed by a dash, followed by one or more numbers, but only match the first set.

---

**In response to your comment**, here's a regex that will check for a number following a `-`, while accounting for potential negative (-) numbers:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\-)\-?\d+");
```

`(?<=\-)` - Negative lookbehind which will check and make sure there is a preceding `-`

`\-?` - Checks for either zero or one dashes

`\d+` - One or more digits

Comment: +1, but note that you don't actually need to escape the `-`: you can just write `\d+(?=-\d+)`. (And for that matter, `(?=\-\d+)` is equivalent to `(?=\-\d)`. I'm not sure which one is clearer.)

Comment: @ruakh I didn't think you had to escape them, but I usually do anyway, since within classes you'll have to. And yeah, I thought of the digit thing too, but I figured i'd keep it that way for clarity's sake

Answer (score 1):

`(?'number'\d+)-` will work, no need to escape. In this example the group containing the single number is the named group `'number'`.
if you want to match both groups with optional sign try:

```
@"(?'first'-?\d+)-(?'second'-?\d+)"
```

Just to describe, nothing complicated, just using `-?` to match an optional `-` and `\d+` to match one or more digit. A literal `-` matches itself.

Comment: Thanks for that.  If I do the same thing above, but with the dash infront -(?'number'\d+) will this return 315?

Comment: @keynesiancross  yes it should

Answer (score 0):

here's some documentation that I use:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

in the comments section of that page, it suggests escaping the dash with `'\-'`

make sure you escape your escape character `\`

Comment: That's only needed inside a character class. Outside a character class, there is no need to escape `-`.

Answer (score 0):

You would escape the special meaning of `-` in regex language (means range) using a `backslash (\)`. Since backslash has a special meaning in C# literals to escape quotes or be part of some characters, you need to escape that with another `backslash(\)`. So essentially it would be `\d+\\-`.

Comment: That's only needed inside a character class. Outside a character class, there is no need to escape `-`.

Answer (score 0):

`\b\d*(?=\-)`  you will want to look ahead for the dash

\b = is start at a word boundry
\d = match any decimal digit
* = match the previous as many times as needed
(?=\-) = look ahead for the dash

Edited for Formatting issue with the slash not showing after posting

Comment: You should use `\d+` rather than `\d*` (because otherwise you'll match between `test` and `-` in a string like `test-test 310-315`). Also, you should use `(?=-)` rather than `+(?=-)` (because only the former is a real regex notation that actually exists).

Comment: `*` means "match zero or more times". So `\d*` will happily match the empty string between `test` and `-`.

Comment: And you don't need to escape the `-` outside a character class.

Comment: \d 
 Matches any decimal digit.
 \d 
 "4" in "4 = IV"    An empty string or whitespace is not a digit

Comment: `\d` does not match the empty string. `\d*` matches the empty string.